# ffmpeg udp stream to file delay

Tags: ffmpeg, udp, video-streaming

I can successfully save/record live UDP stream to a file however there are some messages in console in the begining and a certain amount of delay before recording.
I want to save UDP stream as soon as user clicks on record button so recording should start as realtime as possible.

Comment: On an initial connection ffmpeg probes the stream to figure out which codecs it is using and creates an internal buffer to do so. If you know which codecs the stream uses then you can tell ffmpeg that and cut out that probe delay.

Comment: Thank you for reply but i need more details as the message it shows in console is '[mpeg2video @ 0000000004614620] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
    Last message repeated 14 times' for around 15 seconds

Comment: After an I-frame (video), the rest in the GOP (group of pictures) are constructed from that frame. If you connect to a stream, it's highly likely you will not get an I frame first which decoded the next video frames will be corrupted. Play a recorded TS stream in VLC player and sometimes you will get a grey moving picture until the next I frame appears.